# Maximal abelian subalgebras of different dimensions

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional semisimple complex Lie algebra.

Let $M$ be a subalgebra with the property that *all elements of $M$ are semisimple*, and is maximal w.r.t. this property.

Then $M$ is abelian and its centralizer is itself. So it is maximal abelian subalgebra.

**Q.1** Is it always true that a maximal abelian subalgebra should contain only semisimple elements?

**Q.2** Is it true that two maximal abelian subalgebras can have different dimensions? (I want to know answer to Q. 2 in which one may make cases -  $L$ is emisimple or not semisimple. )

Comment: You may also be interested in this remark on Wikipedia: _A refinement of the Cartan decomposition for symmetric spaces of compact or noncompact type states that the maximal Abelian subalgebras $\mathfrak a$ of $\mathfrak p$ are unique up to conjugation by $K$._ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition

Answer (score 4):

Q.1 Any 1 dimensional Lie subalgebra is abelian so is contained in at least one  maximal abelian subalgebra. So taking any non-semisimple element we find a abelian subalgebra with non-semisimple elements and thus there exist maximal abelian algebras with non-semisimple elements.

Q.2 I think this is best illustrated with some examples in $\mathfrak{sl}_{2n}$:
$$ D = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
        a_1 & \dots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \dots & a_{2n} \\
        \end{pmatrix} : a_i \in \mathbb{C}, \sum_{i=1}^r a_i = 0 \right\} $$
$$ A = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
                0 & 0 \\
                B & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}: B \in \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})\right\} $$
These are both maximal abelian and A has dimension $n^2$ where D has dimension $2n-1$. These examples also fit in the solvable Lie algebra of lower triangular matrices.